# How to upload JSON file in firebase storage (FLUTTER)?

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I want to upload some data to firebase storage as a JSON file and perform read/write over it. I am kinda new to Flutter and unable to figure out how to do this.

For now, I have converted some JSON data to a BLOB and trying to upload that to firebase but I am getting an error using this method.

This is the code to upload data

```
uploadToStorage(file) async {
    var json = {"name": "John", "age": 30, "car": "BMW"};
    var jsonString = jsonEncode(json);
    var blob = new Blob([jsonString], "application/json");
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    var fileRef = firebaseStorageRef.child("/files/test-file.json");
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = fileRef.putData(blob); // The argument type 'Blob' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    var downloadUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
}
```

The error over here is type error but I do not have any idea as to how can I upload the data or change it to Uint8List.

This is the error that I got if I tried changing the JSON string to Uint8List using `Uint8List data = base64.decode(jsonString);`

```
E/flutter ( 9204): #0      _Base64Decoder.decodeChunk  (dart:convert/base64.dart:694:7)
E/flutter ( 9204): #1      _Base64Decoder.decode  (dart:convert/base64.dart:618:14)
E/flutter ( 9204): #2      Base64Decoder.convert  (dart:convert/base64.dart:498:26)
E/flutter ( 9204): #3      Base64Codec.decode  (dart:convert/base64.dart:82:47)
E/flutter ( 9204): #4      StorageUploadState.uploadToStorage 
package:delivero_demo_app/main.dart:102
E/flutter ( 9204): #5      StorageUploadState.callUploadToFirebase 
package:delivero_demo_app/main.dart:90
E/flutter ( 9204): #6      StorageUploadState.initState 
package:delivero_demo_app/main.dart:43
E/flutter ( 9204): #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4682
E/flutter ( 9204): #8      ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4518
E/flutter ( 9204): #9      Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3488
E/flutter ( 9204): #10     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3256
E/flutter ( 9204): #11     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5872
E/flutter ( 9204): #12     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3488
E/flutter ( 9204): #13     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3256
E/flutter ( 9204): #14     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4569
E/flutter ( 9204): #15     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4260
E/flutter ( 9204): #16     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4523
E/flutter ( 9204): #17     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4518
E/flutter ( 9204): #18     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3488
E/flutter ( 9204): #19     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3256
E/flutter ( 9204): #20     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5872
E/flutter ( 9204): #21     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3488
E/flutter ( 9204): #22     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3256
E/flutter ( 9204): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5872
E/flutter ( 9204): #24     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3488
E/flutter ( 9204): #25     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3256
E/flutter ( 9204): #26     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4569
E/flutter ( 9204): #27     StatefulElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4717
E/flutter ( 9204): #28     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4260
E/flutter ( 9204): #29     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4523
E/flutter ( 9204): #30     StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4708
E/flutter ( 9204): #31     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4518
E/flutter ( 9204): #32     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3488
E/flutter ( 9204): #33     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3256
E/flutter ( 9204): #34     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5872
E/flutter ( 9204): #35     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3488
E/flutter ( 9204): #36     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3256
E/flutter ( 9204): #37     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5872
E/flutter ( 9204): #38     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3488
E/flutter ( 9204): #39     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3256
E/flutter ( 9204): #40     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4569
E/flutter ( 9204): #41     StatefulElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4717
E/flutter ( 9204): #42     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4260
E/flutter ( 9204): #43     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4523
E/flutter ( 9204): #44     StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4708
E/flutter ( 9204): #45     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4518
E/flutter ( 9204): #46     Element.inflateWi
```

Any help will be great. Also, is it possible to perform read/write again and again, over the same file present in firebase storage?

Comment: post the error as well please

Comment: @MohammadAssadArshad I have mentioned in a comment that the data type I have is Blob but the `putData` function requires a `Uint8List` so how do I convert the data to that type or is there any other way to do this. This is the type error - `StorageUploadTask uploadTask = fileRef.putData(blob); // The argument type 'Blob' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'.`

Comment: Sorry didn't see your comment; can you try  this instead of using a blob `  var arr = base64.decode(jsonString);` this will give you a Uint8List that you can pass to fileRef.putData.

Comment: @MohammadAssadArshad I have added the error that I got on using this method. Is there any other way using which I can simply upload the JSON data to firebase storage and perform edits to it?

Comment: I am not very sure about other methods, but the error has given me an idea which I have written below in the answer. Please check that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the error , it would mean that the `jsonString` isn't a base64 string which is why it can't be decoded. So can you try like this:

```
 var json = {"name": "John", "age": 30, "car": "BMW"};
 var jsonString = jsonEncode(json);

 var bytes = utf8.encode(jsonString);
 var base64Str = base64.encode(bytes);


 var arr = base64.decode(base64Str); //arr will be Uint8list
```

So basically encode the jsonString first then decode it to give Uint8List. Please give this a try and let me know. This code runs ok on Dartpad, so hope its fine. Thanks